# Find out equation for tangent parallel to x axis

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I solved this problem, but I donť know if I have it correctly.

So,

$f(x)= \dfrac{\ln x}{x}$

Now I am going to derivate $f(x)$ ==> $\dfrac{1-\ln x}{x^2}$

Slope of line on the x axis is $m=0$

Now equation $f'(x) = 0$ becomes
$\dfrac{1-\ln x}{x^2} = 0$

is this the result? equation of tangent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you're not there yet. You need to solve the equation $\frac{1-\ln{x}}{x^2}=0$ for $x$ to find out at what x value the slope of the function $f(x)=\frac{\ln{x}}{x}$ is equal to the "slope" of the x-axis which is $0$.

$$
\frac{1-\ln{x}}{x^2}=0\implies\\
1-\ln{x}=0\implies\\
\ln{x}=1\implies\\
x=e
$$

Then, you're going to use the equation of a tangent line to a curve which is $y=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+f(x_0)$. In your case, $x_0=e$, the slope $f'(x_0)=f'(e)=0$ and $f(x_0)=f(e)=\frac{\ln{e}}{e}=\frac{1}{e}$:

$$
y=f'(e)(x-e)+f(e)\\
y=0+\frac{1}{e}
$$

So, $y=\frac{1}{e}$ is the line you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

No! It allows you to find a point where the slope is 0.
Solving f'(x) = 0 gives x = 1.  Then use the following.

The equation of the tangent to f at the point (a,f(a)) is
y - f(a) = f'(a)(x - a).